# What does IPartition do in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I had a look at the .NET Core source in order to find out whether calls to `IEnumerable.Last()` (LINQ) are optimized when the collection implements `IList` which I suspected to be the case after some quick benchmarking. [It turns out that yes, the input is specifically checked for `IList`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Last.cs#L30), however, even before that, it is checked whether the input implements `IPartition`. [`IPartition` is defined here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Partition.cs#L38), but I do not understand at all what it is supposed to do.

What is the purpose of `IPartition` and how could it possibly be faster than the usually constant-time indexing of `IList` (or if it isn't, why is the input checked for `IPartition` earlier than `IList`)?

Comment: It appears to be used by methods like `Take` to create a subset of the data.    Keep in mind that many linq methods can be invoked before data is fully loaded when using `IQueryable` and the like.  Checking for `IPartition` might allow some sneaky optimizations.

Answer (score 8):

It's an optimization for enumerable methods that act on indexes (Take/Skip and others) when the collection has support for indexes. `IIListProvider` is related.

There are a few [implementations](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Partition.cs). Search the file for `IPartition`.

There are [issues](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?q=IPartition&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) about this.

`IPartition` allows to delegate higher level operations to the underlying collection. For example, `new int[10].Skip(1)` is slow because all data runs through two `IEnumerable<int>`. With the `IPartition` implementation this turns into effectively `for (int i = 1 ... 9) emit(list[i]);`. So it's not using intermediate enumerators and it's calling the list indexer which is slightly faster than enumerating.

This is a very rough description. I encourage you to check out the Github discussions and the code.